# how to fire an event from model B that is present in model A

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
state_machine :device_state, :attribute => :device_state, :initial => :unregistered do
    state :unregistered
    state :registered
    state :compliancy_pending
    state :not_compliant
    state :end_of_contract

    after_transition all => :registered do |device, transition|
      device.update_attributes! :gcm_error => nil
    end

    after_failure do |device, transition|
      Rails.logger.warn "Device #{device.serial_number} failed to transition on #{transition.event} with state #{transition.from_name}"
    end

    event :unregister_device do
      transition all => :unregistered
    end

    event :end_of_contract_device do
      transition all => :end_of_contract
    end

    event :register_device do
      transition [:unregistered, :registered] => :registered
      transition :compliancy_pending => :compliancy_pending
      transition :not_compliant => :not_compliant
    end

    event :requires_dispatch do
      transition [:registered, :compliancy_pending, :not_compliant] => :registered
    end

    event :dispatching do
      transition :registered => :compliancy_pending
      transition [:compliancy_pending] => :compliancy_pending, :unless => :notification_timed_out?
      transition [:registered, :compliancy_pending] => :not_compliant, :if => :notification_timed_out? #gcm_timed_out
    end

    event :device_responded do
      transition [:registered, :not_compliant, :compliancy_pending] => :registered
    end
  end
```

The above is a state machine,also events are specified in this model.
this model is device.rb

but i wand to fire an event from end_of_contract model.

can u please tell me how to use this state machine in another module to update the state.

Description:
 there is a column called device_state,that belongs to device      model(device.rb).
i also have a model end_of_contract.rb and end_of_contractscontroller.rb.
but my task is,when i invoke the end_of_contract operation,it should fire an event present in device.rb and  then the state in this device.rb should be changed to end_of_contract.

LAST,i am new to rails . . .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the event from anywhere as long as you have an instance of device, e.g.

```
@device = Device.find(params[:device_id])
@device.end_of_contract_device
```